# Insert a @"\n" in NSString

Tags: objective-c, string

For example, if I start with this string:

```
NSString * labeltext = @"abcdefghijk";
```

I want this string change to `@"abc\n def\n ghi \n jk"`.

I want @"\n" to be inserted at an interval of 3.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a NSMutableString and then for loop through the original NSString.

```
NSMutableString *buffer = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
int len = [labelText length];
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    NSRange charAt = NSMakeRange(i,1);
    [buffer appendString: [labelText substringWithRange: charAt]];
    if ((i % 3) == 2) {
        [buffer appendString: @"\n"];
    }
}
labelText = (NSString *)buffer;
```

The above example is pure Objective-C.  This can also be accomplished using C.  Convert the NSString into a cstring and then loop through the array.  For instance,

```
const char *str = [labelText UTF8String];
int len = strlen(str) - 1;
int pos = 0;
char buffer[(len * 2) + 1];
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    char ch = str[i];
    buffer[pos] = ch;
    pos++;
    if ((i % 3) == 2) {
        buffer[pos] = '\n';
        pos++;
    }
}
buffer[pos] = '\0';
labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s", buffer];
```